# State not being update on app startup with zustand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zustand

The issue: On startup after the splashscreen is shown the List screen shows all users. When app is first loaded useEffect() is being called but the state update is not causing a rerender. However this only happen on startup, if I navigate on another screen and come back to it eveything happens as it should be.

```
const fetch = async () => {
   useStore.setState({ allUsers: await getAllUsers() });
};

useEffect(() => {
  fetch();
}, []);
```

and my zustand store is defined as below :

```
  type Store = {
     allUsers: User[];
     
  };

  export const useStore = create<Store>((set) => ({
     allUsers: [],
     
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The useEffect has no dependency to trigger a re-render. `useEffect` with no dependency array will be only called once when the component mounts.

If the desired effect is to display updated data after `fetch()` is complete add the state as a dependency to the `useEffect` hook.

Like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch()
},[])
```

Change to:

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch()
}, [useMazlsStore]);
```

For more information on how `useEffect` lifecycles work chekc out [this article](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-react-useeffect-hook-lifecycle-methods/)